# Radio buttons keep sending wrong values

Tags: php, android

I'm new to Android and I recently had a homework: one of the activities will send values from radio buttons and some text views to the database, but when I try to run it and check my database, it keeps showing wrong values. The only radio button sending the right value is the first one.

This is the activity:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Test extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView idm, nama_mk, kls, mhw_mk;
    Button submit;
    String P1 = "1";
    String P2 = "1";
    String P3 = "1";
    String P4 = "1";
    String P5 = "1";
    RadioGroup cho1;
    RadioGroup cho2;
    RadioGroup cho3;
    RadioGroup cho4;
    RadioGroup cho5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.test);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            cho1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
            cho1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.A1:
                        P1 = "1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.B1:
                        P1 = "2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.C1:
                        P1 = "3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.D1:
                        P1 = "4";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            cho2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
            cho2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.A2:
                        P2 = "1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.B2:
                        P2 = "2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.C2:
                        P2 = "3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.D2:
                        P2 = "4";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            cho3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
            cho3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.A3:
                        P3 = "1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.B3:
                        P3 = "2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.C3:
                        P3 = "3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.D3:
                        P3 = "4";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            cho4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice4);
            cho4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.A4:
                        P2 = "1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.B4:
                        P2 = "2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.C4:
                        P2 = "3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.D4:
                        P2 = "4";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            cho5 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choice5);
            cho5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.A5:
                        P3 = "1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.B5:
                        P3 = "2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.C5:
                        P3 = "3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.D5:
                        P3 = "4";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });


            idm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nim_mhs);
            nama_mk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_mk);
            kls = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kelas);
            mhw_mk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_mhw_mk);
            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        new EntryData().execute();
                }
            });
        }

        public class EntryData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            String success;

            String url_link = "http://wwwww/xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz.php";

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String strnama = nama_mk.getText().toString();
                String stremail = idm.getText().toString();
                String strpassword = kls.getText().toString();
                String strmhwmk = mhw_mk.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matakuliah", strnama));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idmahasiswa", stremail));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", strpassword));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_mhw_mk", strmhwmk));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1", P1));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p2", P2));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p3", P3));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p4", P4));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p5", P5));

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_link, "POST", nvp);
                try {
                    success = json.getString("success");
                    if (success == "1") {

                        Intent forum = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForumActivity.class);                    
                        forum.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(forum);                   
                        finish();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return null;
            }

        }

        public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                        String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        str.append(line);
                    }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return str.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$id_mhs=$_POST['idmahasiswa'];
$nama_mk = $_POST['matakuliah'];
$kelas=$_POST['kelas'];
$id_mhw_mk=$_POST['id_mhw_mk'];
$pert1=$_POST['p1'];
$pert2=$_POST['p2'];
$pert3=$_POST['p3'];
$pert4=$_POST['p4'];
$pert5=$_POST['p5'];
$periode=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
include "koneksi.php";


$query = "INSERT INTO main_hasil_raw (idmahasiswa,matakuliah,kelas,id_mhw_mk,periode,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)VALUES('$id_mhs','$nama_mk','$kelas','$id_mhw_mk','$periode','$pert1','$pert2','$pert3','$pert4','$pert5')";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
if($hasil)
    {
    $response["success"] = "1";
        $response["message"] = "Data sukses diinput";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {$response["success"] = "0";
     $response["message"] = "Maaf , terjadi kesalahan";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

And the layout (if needed):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nim_mhs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kelas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Kelas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nama_mk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="Nama Matakuliah"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

         <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="1.Question One"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/choice1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="2. Question Two"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/choice2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="3. Question Three"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/choice3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow> 

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="4. Question Four"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/choice4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow> 

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="5. Question Five"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/choice5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow> 

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_mhw_mk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can you help/teach me to solve this problem?

Comment: why you give me -1? please explain, i'm new to this forum

Comment: You are asking some debugging help like to find us where you made mistake.SO does not accept those type of question.May be someone downvoted for that reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cho4` and `cho5` checkboxes you are reusing the variables `P2` and `P3`, is this intentional?

(I would have put this as a comment but I don't have the required reputation)